# Ultimate image optimization solution

Tags: wordpress, image, pagespeed

I am looking for an ultimate, final word solution for the image optimization issue. My goal is to get no comment from the [Google PageSpeed Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) tool when analyzing my website. I know the trick that you can click on the 'download optimized images ...' link that the tool offers when you have unoptimized images, but I am looking for an ultimate solution for a wordpress web developer, that every image I upload to the media will be optimized 100% for the Google standards, no issues, no concerns. I am also ready to pay for a premium plugin if it really does the job. 
I already tried:
- [tinypng / tinyjpg](http://tinypng.com) 
- [wp-smushit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/)
They don't please the gods.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] a good question and the perfect question and how to [create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **SO is not a free** Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service.

Answer (score 0):

You can install WordPress Smush image plugin that will optimized images when you upload new images and for current images you have to do it manually.

There is a

Answer (score 0):

So, it would not be so easy to achieve. In September 2017 Google Pagespeed change rules of the game. Now they want all images to be smaller then webp q75 + 10%. If you compress your images with jpeg to achieve such small file size - you will get terrible artifacts. So now there is no other way except using webp images.

Currently only Chrome and Opera support webp images. So you can't convert all your images to webp. You should use dual files system. Create two files for each image (including thumbnails), and serve webp images to webp browsers and non webp images to non webp browsers. This can be done by mod_rewrite. The following code in .htaccess will do it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*(jpe?g|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>
AddType image/webp .webp
```

There are two ways to generate webp duplicates in your Wordpress site.

1. Use of commercial plug-ins, such as WP Smush, EWWW Image optimizer.
   They are supper cool, but you will need to pay for them.
2. Use of free plugins. Most of them want to have image encoders to be installed in your server. I have found only one free plugin that does not need encoders to be installed in server. It is Opti MozJpeg Guetzli WebP. But it wants encoders to be installed in your computer. It works through ssh. You run virtual machine with linux and encoders in your computer (it can be downloaded from plugin's homepage) and connect this plugin to virtual machine via ssh. A bit tricky. But it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many, but ImageOptim one is excellent and Free.

If you are using **Mac** use ImageOptim --> https://imageoptim.com/mac

[Online interface](https://imageoptim.com/online) — a JPEG compressor that produces smaller, higher quality files. The web interface works with any system.

For **Windows**, you can try below.

[FileOptimizer](https://nikkhokkho.sourceforge.io/static.php?page=FileOptimizer) — supports many file formats, and it's Free and Open Source.

[pngquant](https://pngquant.org/#download) — lossy PNG compressor. It has some Windows-compatible GUI apps and Photoshop plug-ins available.

After you optimise images locally, upload those to your server.